improve dataframe performance for large datasets
I have a large datasets need to filter out root packages as below:

sort data(package column) by string length.
start from beginning, scan the following data, if it starts with current data, then mark it as False.
repeat step 2 till end.

To improve performance, I add a flag column to keep track it's processed or not.
Sound like now the big-O is n instead of n square. anything we can improve?
The obvious one is the second for loop, now use continue to skip previous items, maybe more better way do do that?
import re
import pandas as pd
import tabulate

def dumpdf(df):
    if len(df) == 0: return
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    tab = tabulate.tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql',showindex=True)
    print(tab)
    return

def main():
    data = [
        ['A','com.example'],
        ['A','com.example.a'],
        ['A','com.example.b.c'],
        ['A','com.fun'],
        ['B','com.demo'],
        ['B','com.demo.b.c'],
        ['B','com.fun'],
        ['B','com.fun.e'],
        ['B','com.fun.f.g']
        ]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['name','package'])
    df ['flag'] = None
    df = df.sort_values(by="package", key=lambda x: x.str.len()).reset_index(drop=True)
    for idx,row in df.iterrows():
        if row['flag'] == None:
            df.loc[idx,'flag'] = True
            for jdx, jrow in df.iterrows():
                if jdx <= idx: continue
                if row['name'] == jrow['name']:
                    if jrow['package'].startswith(row['package']):
                         df.loc[jdx,'flag'] = False

    #
    df = df[df['flag']]
    df = df.groupby('name',as_index=False).agg({'package':'\n'.join})
    dumpdf(df)
    return

main()




IIUC you can do:
from functools import cmp_to_key
from itertools import groupby


def fn(g):
    out = []
    for _, k in groupby(g.sort_values(), cmp_to_key(lambda a, b: not b.startswith(a))):
        out.append(next(k))
    return pd.Series(out)


out = df.groupby("name")["package"].apply(fn).droplevel(1).reset_index()

print(out)

Prints:
  name      package
0    A  com.example
1    A      com.fun
2    B     com.demo
3    B      com.fun


Good answer, it's really fast. is it a linear complexity?

@beetlej There's sort, so n log n
